# Windows 10, 32 bit? or Windows 7, 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, 64-bit, 32-bit

I know that Both operating systems are good.. But looking for a Complete Stable, performance giving OS, is hard to choose between these two...
Like asking:

Light DirectX 12, but System Compatibility Limitation?
Or
Light DirectX 10 But older Operating system?

Windows 10, 32 bit - Requires 1 GB-- 
Windows 7, 64 Bit - Requires 2 GB

I am looking for an OS, that can go with this ol' lady:

Acer Extensa 5220.

EDIT:
the thing includes 2 GB of DDR2 RAM
an x64 based Processor (But slow)..
And pretty much anything else, is [here.](http://www.laptopreviewsonline.com/AcerLaptop/Extensa5220/)

any other things, i need to clarify?

Comment: 1GB or 2GB of RAM?

Comment: @cybernard Take a look at [this page](https://ark.intel.com/products/29830/Intel-82GL960-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller), which says, "Max Memory Size: 2 GB".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  Missed that, run away from any device that only supports 2gb of RAM.

Comment: It will probably work either way - the problem lies on any answer provided is most likely purely on opinion (or anecdotal).  I have a Win10 32 bit running on 2GB machine (netbook) and even dual boot with Debian - and works either way.

Answer (score 0):

In general, newer OS version will provide more new function and improved performance.

Besides, 64 bit system is recommended:
1.  It supports both 32 bit and 64 bit software. 
2.  64 bit can handle large amounts of memory more efficiently than a 32-bit, it can be more responsive when running several programs at the same time and switching between them frequently.

Hardware and hardware driver compatibility are also important. Search on your hardware/device official website according to your hardware model, if it supports Windows 10 and has appropriate drivers, I would recommend you to install Windows 10. Otherwise, Windows 7 would be recommended.